# error while loading shared libraries: libgdal.so.1 in archlinux

Tags: django, gis, gdal, archlinux

I (myself a programm novice) get the following error message when starting a script in archlinux, which has been written by a friend:

```
/usr/bin/psxy: error while loading shared libraries: libgdal.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/psbasemap: error while loading shared libraries: libgdal.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ps2raster: error while loading shared libraries: libgdal.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/psxy: error while loading shared libraries: libgdal.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

At that point in the script it uses the [Generic Mapping Tools](http://gmt.soest.hawaii.edu/) (GMT). I think the problem is a linker problem and related to `gdal`. The version installed is:

```
gdalinfo --version
GDAL 2.0.0, released 2015/06/14
```

And, indeed, `libgdal.so.1` is not installed (or has been renamed to `/usr/lib/libgdal.so`?):

```
/sbin/ldconfig -p | grep gdal
    libgdal.so.20 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libgdal.so.20
    libgdal.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libgdal.so
```

But when I want to install `gdal1`, then it comes to a conflict with the already installed `gdal` (which I presume is 2.0).

What can I do? Do I have to edit the script and if so, where, to make it use of gdal?

**Edit:**
I enter `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib` before executing the script with the same error message as above.

I have, then, tried to edit the `ldconfig` file by `locate libgdal`:

```
/usr/lib/libgdal.so
/usr/lib/libgdal.so.20
/usr/lib/libgdal.so.20.0.0

nano /etc/ld.so.conf -> adding /usr/lib/
```

But `/sbin/ldconfig -p | grep gdal` still shows:

```
libgdal.so.20 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libgdal.so.20
libgdal.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libgdal.so
```

Comment: try: `ln -s /usr/lib/libgdal.so /usr/lib/libgdal.so.1` and run `/sbin/ldconfig` after

Comment: Yeah, that helped! You rock!

Comment: Good, I'll post the answer in case someone else search for it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can make a symbolic links to that library so your application can find it:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/libgdal.so /usr/lib/libgdal.so.1
```

after that, run this command to configure dynamic linker run-time bindings:

```
/sbin/ldconfig
```