# Postgresql could not load library

Tags: postgresql, postgis

after days of regular fight with postgis I stuck on this:

```
 postgres=# CREATE EXTENSION postgis; ERROR:  could not load library
 "/usr/pgpro-9.6/lib/rtpostgis-2.4.so": libgdal.so.20: cannot open
 shared object file: No such file or directory
```

and have no idea how to pass it, because library path is correct...

```
[combat@urpordfinal ~]$ ls -alt /usr/pgpro-9.6/lib/ total 13080

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root     root     1440056 Apr 23 11:52 postgis_topology-2.4.so 
drwxr-xr-x 5 root     root        8192 Apr 23 11:52 .
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root     root     1878728 Apr 23 11:52 rtpostgis-2.4.so
```

I'm running pgsql 9.6.8 and psotgis build from source

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32807686/2025395

Answer (score 2):

You have to make sure that `libgdal.so.20` is on the shared library path.

Find out where the library is and add that directory to the shared library path.

On Linux, you would normally do that by adding the directory to `/etc/ld.so.conf` (or, better, to a PostGIS configuration file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d`) and running `ldconfig`.